# conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL query. While executing this query, i am getting above error

```
WITH Results_CTE AS (select Top 20 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeyId desc) AS SNo,* from(select * from (  select ps.Id as KeyId,dps.Id as SettingId,dps.DocumentType,dps.DocumentProcessingType,null as Description,null as Link
            from [ParttimerSalary] ps inner join [ParttimerEmployee] pe on pe.Id = ps.ParttimerEmployeeId 
            inner Join [DocumentProcessingSetting] dps on dps.Step = ps.Step and dps.KeyId = pe.ParttimerType and 
            (dps.RoleId = 'e218e9e0-d51d-45b4-9380-77f43ac50f0d' or dps.UserId = '1967681a-7d64-486e-99a8-4b58746cef81') and dps.DocumentType = 2 union all 
            Select 'Incident/service is assigned for you' as [Description],'#/it/incidentsupport/' as Link,0 as Id,0 as SettingId,0 as DocumentType,0 as DocumentProcessingType from Incident where IncidentStatus = 2 and SupportById = '1967681a-7d64-486e-99a8-4b58746cef81'
            )wrapped) listing ORDER BY KeyId desc) SELECT * FROM Results_CTE WHERE SNo >= 0 AND SNo <=20
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While using Union all the datatype should match in both the select elements.

- ps.Id as KeyId is a unique identifer whereas 'Incident/service is assigned for you' as [Description] is character string that's the reason for error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had changed the order of selecting columns from the table after union keyword, as during union, we need manage the order,datatype, etc of field of the both tables
And the problem was solved.
Anyway thanks